# Confusion on flux definition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow

In the context of fluid mechanics, flux is the quantity per time per area and one could calculate the total movement of that quantity per unit of time through a control surface by

$$\iint{}flux(S,t)dS$$

However when learning about electromagnetism electric flux is defined as

$$flux=\iint{}E(S,t)dS$$

How can both results be consistent with one definition? In the first, the quantity would be calculated by integrating the flux. In the second, the flux ***is*** the quantity be calculated. Is there something I am missing or is this truly an inconsistency?

Comment: The term is used differently in the two contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flux is a mathematical quantity that can be defined for any vector field. The flux of the field $\vec{F}$ through some surface $a$ is 
$$
\Phi = \int \limits_a \vec{F}(\vec{r},t) \cdot \hat{a} ~da.
$$

In the case of fluid mechanics, the vector field is the momentum or velocity field of the fluid, and so corresponds to a mass passing through the surface, or total flow rate respectively.

In the case of E&M, both the electric and magnetic fields have meaningful fluxes in the theory. However, the meaning is not the rate at which matter passes through the surface, it is instead related to the rate at which the other type of field is induced.

Comment: That made  lot of sense. Especially with the examples you gave. So in fluid mechanics the flux would be the volume of fluid passing while the flux density would be the fluid velocity.

Comment: That sounds like the basic idea, if by flux density you mean $\vec{F}$ and by volume of fluid you mean the rate at which volume passes through the surface.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant